# How can I add action Items to a subscription after it has been activated?

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs

I'm trying to build a service in angular that manages the database the problem is that I am trying to store the subscriptions on the service class and not the component class so they are all in the same place however as I understand it, the callback for a subscription needs to be defined when the subscription is activated is there any way to add to a subscription after it has been activated? I looked at the .add() operator but that seems to work only when the subscription is canceled.

**EDIT**
below is the best function I could come up with; it works but it doesn't seem elegant or even best practice

```
  test(col, doc, callback) {
    (this[col][doc] as Observable<unknown>) = this.afs
      .collection(col)
      .doc(doc)
      .valueChanges().subscribe(val => {callback(val)})
  }
```

Comment: As a secondary question I think the deeper problem is that I don't fully understand how RXJS really works and am just regurgitating code that I get from online resources and courses, is does anyone know of a good course I could take online that could take me from 0 to pro?

Comment: Could you provide some code in order to be more helpful ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer by watching a completely unrelated video, on angular, the answer is not to subscribe at all and return an observable from the service finally use the async pipe to unwrap the observable

Comment: `async` subscribes to the observable under the hood - but you are right, it's best not to manually subscribe.